# How to say 'likes it when' in Japanese

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese

I was wondering how I would say sentences such as

1. [Person A] **likes it when** [Person B] [performs an action].
2. [Person A] **likes it when** [noun] is [adjective].
3. [Person A] **likes it when** [an action is being performed].

My guess for sentences of this form would be something like

> 1. Hanako likes it when Yuki makes new friends.
>    花子さんは雪さんが新しい友達を作るのが好きです。
> 2. Hanako likes it when the roads are quiet.
>    花子さんは静かな道の時が好きです。
> 3. Hanako likes it when her room is being cleaned.
>    花子さんは誰か部屋を掃除しているのが好きです。

Update: Edited to be about general structure rather than direct translation, and to indicate my prior research, and to include my own guesses of sample sentences.

Comment: "Hanako likes it when her car is being cleaned" would be the same as "Hanako likes her car being cleaned". There's no direct analogue of your original phrases (probably because of the difficulty of expressing 'it' in Japanese). If you don't know how to express the latter construction it should be easy to search for.

Comment: Also, [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: @user3856370 So how do you say [Person A] likes [noun] [being/having action performed on it]? What tenses and particles should I use?

Comment: @SpikedHelmet We are more concerned of whether you did due research to understand it and make clear what (you think) you know and what you don't. For example, how do you think you'd translate it?

Comment: @brokenlaptop I use google first. 'Likes it when' didn't turn up the results I was looking for. These are my guesses:
花子さんさんは誰か部屋を掃除するのが好きです。
花子さんは静かな道の時が好きです。
花子さんは雪さんが新しい友達を作るのが好きです。

Comment: @SpikedHelmet Can you include your Japanese sentences in the question text as examples along with original English(?) that you intended to say?

Comment: @brokenlaptop I updated the question. Would I be able to get it reopened?

Comment: 「静かな道の時」 doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [嬉]{うれ}しい, such as in:

> Hanako likes it when Yuki makes new friends.
> 花子さんは、雪さんに新しい友達ができるのが嬉しい。
> 花子さんは、雪さんに新しい友達ができると嬉しい。
>
> Hanako likes it when the roads are quiet.
> 花子さんは、道が静かなのが嬉しい。
> 花子さんは、道が静かだと嬉しい。
>
> Hanako likes it when her room is being cleaned.
> 花子さんは、部屋を掃除してもらうのが嬉しい。
> 花子さんは、部屋を掃除してもらうと嬉しい。

Answer (score 0):

I feel like *いい感じがする* suits these kinds of sentences because it's not so much 'like' as it is 'have a good feeling'.

1. 花子さんは、自分の部屋が掃除されている時は**いい感じがする**。
2. 花子さんは道が静かな時**いい感じがする**。(A bit unsure about this one)
3. 花子さんは雪さんが新しい友達を作るたびに**いい感じがする**。(In this case, it's not so much 'when' as it is 'whenever')